# How do I include a gradle composite build into a multi project build?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build, build.gradle

I have a project that is a library (ProjectLib) and is used in many other projects. I have another project which is a multi project build (MultiProject) with a few sub projects (SubProj1, SubProj2, CoreProj). Some of these sub projects depend on the library project.
Normally I have the sub projects that depend on the library have the library specified in the dependency block of each of their build scripts and it fetches a built version of my library.
Sometimes I have to develop something in my library for this multi project and while doing this I would like to include the library as a composite build so that I can make changes and see the effect in the multi project build.

I have tried adding the path to my library in the settings.gradle of the root project using 'includeBuild' but this only half works.

What I tried is this:

MultiProject settings.gradle

```
include "SubProj1", "SubProj2", "CoreProj"
includeBuild "../ProjectLib"
```

SubProj1 and SubProj2 build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":CoreProj")
    implementation "com.myCompany:ProjectLib:1.0.0"
}
```

The build file for the CoreProj doesn't depend on the ProjectLib.

My ProjectLib normally builds to a private repo which is fetched by gradle and so typically version 1.0.0 would be included from this repo. What I would like to happen is that instead of fetching this version of the library, gradle instead includes the project in my local directory so that it has my latest changes without me having to build and release the library to the repo.
What I am getting at the moment is that the ProjectLib is being included in my IDE (I am using IntelliJ) but I get the following warning:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.UnknownConfigurationException: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
This warning appears twice for my MultiProject and the once each for SubProj1 and SubProj2. This also breaks up my project structure in my IDE so that it looks like only CoreProj is included in the multi project build MultiProject.

I am using gradle 5.5.1

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue in the meantime? I'm having a different yet similar issue in that multi-projects with included builds don't seem to work well in certain cases.